firebase function does not work correctly with swift, but works with a direct html request
I have a simple cloud function gen1 that accepts settings and returns a response from the "chat gpt" it sends, it is written in Python 3, which works great directly through the request, but when I try to do the same with the help of swift, it returns an error: Error: FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: 3) , INVALID ARGUMENT, nil.
(everything worked when sending only the request text in the gpt configuration to the python function)
enter image description here
cloud function:
import openai
import requests
from flask import jsonify

openai_api_key = 'API_KEY'

url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {openai_api_key}"
}


def chat_function(request):
    try:
        request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
        if not request_json:
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid request, JSON required"}), 400

        # Перевіряємо, чи є ключ 'model' та 'messages' у запиті
        model = request_json.get('model')
        messages = request_json.get('messages')

        if not model or not messages:
            return jsonify({"error": "Model and messages are required"}), 400

        data = {
            "model": model,
            "messages": messages
        }

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            reply = response.json()['choices'][0]['message']['content']
            return jsonify({"response": reply})
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": response.status_code, "message": response.text}), response.status_code

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


swift:
import UIKit
import FirebaseFunctions

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var functions = Functions.functions()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let data: [String: Any] = [
            "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            "messages": [
                ["role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."],
                ["role": "user", "content": "Hello!"]
            ]
        ]
        
        functions.httpsCallable("chat_function").call("data: {\(data)} ") { result, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                    let message = error.localizedDescription
                    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                    print("Error: \(code ?? .unknown), \(message), \(String(describing: details))")
                }
            }
            if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["response"] as? String {
                print("Response from Cloud Function: \(text)")
            }
            print(result?.data)
        }
    }
}


I tried different date formats:


// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
 let model: String
 let messages: [Message]
}

// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable {
 let role, content: String
}

let messages = [
 Message(role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant."),
 Message(role: "user", content: "print(2) what is language?")
 ]

 let dataClass = DataClass(model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", messages: messages)

also added {data: ..... before dataClass or tried to send a complete string.

Your cloud function is not a "callable" type function, so you can't use the Firebase SDK httpsCallable to invoke it.  You should just write your client to make a normal HTTP request and skip the Firebase SDK entirely.

I found the answer. you need to add a line to Python:
data = request_json.get('data')
model = data.get('model')
messages = data.get('messages')
